# Remove gradle task build dependencies

Tags: gradle

In gradle 2 I wrote a script to clear all the build dependencies for a task. I wrote it so I can upload my artifact without rebuilding it:

```
project.task('stageMyEar', type: Upload) {

    configuration = getDefaultConfiguration()
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${projectProperty('releaseArtifactoryUrl')}"
            credentials {
                username "${projectProperty('releaseArtifactoryUsername')}"
                password "${projectProperty('releaseArtifactoryPassword')}"
            }
        }
    }
}

private getDefaultConfiguration() {

    def defaultConfiguration = project.configurations.archives

    defaultConfiguration.artifacts.each {
        it.buildDependencies.values.clear()
    }

    project.version = 'current'

    return defaultConfiguration
}
```

When I run this in gradle 4 I get the following error:

No such property: values for class: No such property: values for class: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskDependency

When I look at the new DefaultTaskDependency code the values are gone and in their place there are immutableValues and mutableValues. Clearing the mutableValues does not have the same result which I had with clearing values.

How can I get the same result as buildDependencies.values.clear() in gradle 4